# How to config a angular.js provider dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

The use case is that I have a custom service which needs to be configured based on user input.

So I created a service provider for that service, but now I can only config the provider inside the module.config call, which I think it is loaded only once during the life of the app.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Anyone's guess why you can't you pass parameters from user input into a service and process them without seeing some code or far more detailed explanation

Comment: It sounds like you want a service that doesn't work as a singleton but instead outputs some kind of instance of a class. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Have your service provide some sort of a configuration API to set these configuration values as needed. As a simple example you might do something like this:

```
function myController(myService, $scope) {
  $scope.config = myService.config;
  // You can manipulate various config options now through direct binding.
}
```

However remember that AngularJS services are singletons, which means they will all share the same state. If you need different state, or need a "new" one each time you will want to do something more like the way $resource or $http works which is basically a factory.

```
function myController(myService, $scope) {
  $scope.config = { value1: 'default', value2: 'default' };
  var thisService = myService($scope.config);
  // You can manipulate various config options now through direct binding.
}
```

Just remember that services are basically objects and you can manipulate them as per your design as you need. So these are probably not the only, or even necessarily the best way to accomplish your goal. You have total flexibility here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a service's provider is what you are looking for here because it is precisely just what you describe it.

As Chris stated, angular services are singletons. However, if you want your service to output "instances" based on user input, I like the following approach.

```
function myController(myService, $scope) {
  var config = { value1: 'default', value2: 'default' };
  $scope.newInstance=myService.create(config);

}

app.service('myService', [function(){

   function serviceInstance = function (config){
     //take config and return output object
   }

   return {
      create: function(config){
         return new serviceInstance(config);
      }
   }
}]);
```

I haven't thought about being able to manipulate the config variables as Chris suggested. I don't think it would work in my example but you could data bind to the `$scope.newInstance`